# XY coordinates to quadtree in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates, quadtree

I want to convert Converts tile XY coordinates into a QuadKey at a specified level of detail.

I need to do this in Javascript. To Illustrate the problematic you will find an exact description here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx and there you can also find the function in C#. The function name is: tileXYToQuadKey.

I need to implement it in Javascript. Here is the JSFiddle that I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/cueqzapper/m44bgk1p/

```
var tileXYToQuadKey = function(tileX, tileY, levelOfDetail)
{
    quadKey = 'q';
    for (var i = levelOfDetail; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var digit = 0;
        var mask = 1 << (i - 1);
        console.log(mask);
        if ((tileX & mask) != 0)
        {
            digit++;
        }
        if ((tileY & mask) != 0)
        {
            digit++;
            digit++;
        }
        quadKey += 't' + digit;
    }
    return quadKey;
}
console.log(tileXYToQuadKey(1,1,2));
```

But something is wrong. When I call the function like this: tileXYToQuadKey(1,1,2) I get qt0t3 back. But correct would be qt0t0, because the tile with the coordinates x=1, y=1 would obviously be at the top left corner, and that means it would have the quad key of 00.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The implementation of the function is right, and so are the results. The tile in (1,1) has a quadkey of 03. It is not the top left corner: the top-left corner tile is (0,0).

Comment: Yes you are right. Everything is correct here. The coordinates are just not starting with (1,1), they start with (0,0). Thanks anyway!

Comment: The quadkey is t0t3 not 30.

Comment: true. I'm changing it

Answer (score 0):

In the bing maps from your link you can see the quadkey t0t3 of level 2 is the tile at x=1 and y=1. The coordinates starts with (0,0) and you are looking at level 2! At level the quadkey is qt3.